# Drupal webform, how can i make a form that triggers a php script with GET arguments?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, form-submit, drupal-webform

I want to create a form in Drupal 7.
User will select appropriate listbox, radio button options.
When user clicks Submit button, form will post related values to another php file with GET arguments.

- Default submit button shows a confirmation page for email sending/registration. I couldn't make the form to post arguments to a php file by changing submit behaviour of the form.

For two days I tried Webform module to do this.
I would be happy if you can recommend me some way to make this? Examples, tryouts, modules, codes, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 'better' ways but this will do the trick in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $nid = 1; // Or whatever the node ID of your webform is
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_' . $nid) {
    $form['#action'] = 'my-script.php';
    $form['#method'] = 'get';
  }
}
```

Bear in mind of course that the original webform submission functions will not run so your webform data won't be saved to the database.

Comment: * What can be "better" ways? are they hard to implement?   * I couldn't find the form's id, where can i check it?   *  If I put my own form html to node, how can i change form submit value, or what should i write to action part of form, node address?         Thank you

Comment: The 'better' ways are harder to implement, yes, it would involve using the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7) to build up your own form and then using the submission function to perform whatever task you needed to in your external script. You can check the webform's `nid` by going to it's edit page and looking at the url: `node/NID/edit`